# Spring Data REST - Is it required implement repository for each concrete class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have the following two classes defined in my Spring Data REST project.

**Person.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public abstract class Person implements Serializable, Identifiable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

}
```

**Employee.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Employee extends Person{


    private String employeeNumber;

}
```

I have implemented the Person repository and I can use it to persist Employee resources as well by registering a `SimpleAbstractTypeResolver` as follows.

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule("MyCustomModule") {
            @Override
            public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                context.addAbstractTypeResolver(
                        new SimpleAbstractTypeResolver().addMapping(Person.class, Employee.class)
                );
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I get the following response when I send a GET to the `persons` endpoint.

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "employees": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "employeeNumber": "X-11",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/employee/1"
                    },
                    "employee": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/employee/1{?projection}",
                        "templated": true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/persons{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/persons"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

However when I call the link `http://localhost:8080/employee/1` I get a `404 Not Found` error message. So am I doing something wrong? Do I have to implement a new  repository for every concrete class?

Comment: What for do you use the class `Person`?

Comment: `Person` is an abstract class which is extended by the `Employee` class.

Comment: Do you have any other use for `Person`?

Comment: Probably not. It is strictly for inheritance.

Comment: Why don't you just drop `Person` then? It makes no sense to have a super class if you inherit it exactly once...

Comment: I have actually simplified the domain to post the question. There are other classes which extends `Person`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157140/discussion-between-delta-charlie-and-herr-derb).

Comment: It looks like I talked complete crap. Have a look here:https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/06/06/the-best-way-to-use-entity-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I checked out the blog post but it is more related to domain design so it still doesnt answer my question

Comment: It is strange that the json references "employees" and the link references employee/1 when you are htting  the  persons endpoint. Remove the custom object mapper to see if that is causing issues. I would probably provide repositories/endpoints for all concrete classes as it is more flexible i.e. I can get all persons /persons employees only /employees etc.

Comment: So what could be a possible solution for this? I am actually trying to use a single repository for all concrete classes of `Person`

Comment: In that case does it make sense to keep a repository for the parent class?